# How to pass operator << for string as parameter?

Tags: c++

I want to do something like that:

```
vector<string> road_map;
// do some stuff
for_each(road_map.begin(), road_map.end(), bind(cout, &ostream::operator<<));
```

Note: I don't want to use lambda for this purpose, like that:

```
[](const string& str){ cout << str << endl; }
```

C++ compiler will create aux code for lambda. That's why I don't want to use lambda in such case. I suppose that there is more lightweight solution for such problem. Of course it is not critical, if there is not simple solution I just will use lambda.

Comment: What's wrong with using a lambda? It is well suited for this task. What problem are you actually experiencing? You need to be more specific.

Comment: C++ compiler will generate extra aux code for lambdas, I suppose that there is more lightweight solution just using operator<<.

Comment: @LmTinyToon Because `bind` is a lightweight solution? Actually, why not simply use a ranged-base for loop in this case?

Comment: I wanted to get short code using functional style. Yes, I agree bind is not best solution rather lambda.

Comment: "C++ compiler will generate extra aux code for lambdas". Why do you care? Have you verified that it will create an unacceptable performance bottleneck? Each `cout <<` will likely take about 1,000,000 times longer than any additional code generated by the lambda.

Comment: @n.m., It seems like you are right. `cout << ` is actually heavy operation.

Comment: A lambda or a range-based loop are very likely to generate better code, since the compiler will insert the loop anyway. The bind variant may also generate the same code, but I won't be surprised, if that code would be worse, since bind objects can be heavyweight. Also you should look at std::ostream_iterator, it does exactly what you are try to achieve.

Comment: Also note that when you bind `operator <<`, you will have no delimiters between the different strings.

Comment: `C++ compiler will create aux code for lambda` that will be optimized away most likely

Comment: Even if there was a way to do what you want (I'm not sure), you think `std::bind()` won't cause the compiler to create "auxiliary code"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an ostream_iterator to generate the output.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> road_map{"ab", "cde"};
    // do some stuff
    std::copy(road_map.begin(), road_map.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer is mainly used to investigate the `C++ compiler will create aux code for lambda` claim.

You should note that there is no member function `ostream::operator<<` taking a `std::string`. There's only a free-standing function [opertator<<(std::ostream&,const std::string&)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) defined in the `<string>` header.

I used gcc godbolt, you can see the example [Live here](https://godbolt.org/g/HtgEw4)

So I made a version using a lambda and a version using std::bind:

With bind you get

```
void funcBind(std::vector<std::string>& a) 
{
    using namespace std;
    using func_t = std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&, const std::string&);
    func_t fptr = &operator<<; //select the right overload
    std::for_each(
        a.begin(),
        a.end(), 
        std::bind(
            fptr,
            std::ref(std::cout),
            std::placeholders::_1)
    );
}
```

and this assembly on x86_64

```
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     rbp, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        cmp     rbx, rbp
        je      .L22
.L24:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbx+8]
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        add     rbx, 32
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        cmp     rbp, rbx
        jne     .L24
.L22:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

and with a lambda you get:

```
void  funcLambda(std::vector<std::string>& a)  
{
  std::for_each(
    a.begin(),
    a.end(),
    [](const std::string& b){std::cout << b;});
}
```

and this assembly

```
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     rbp, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        cmp     rbx, rbp
        je      .L27
.L29:
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbx+8]
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        add     rbx, 32
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        cmp     rbp, rbx
        jne     .L29
.L27:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

so you don't actually see any difference with any appreciable level of optimization enable